# search xml file for any occurrence in search string

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom

When searchterm is one of the keywords(e.g. 'driver' or 'white) it gives the results and it seems to be ok, but whenever searchterm is extended to 'driver 102' or 'R-22 red' nothing happens.

( used RegEx expressions, escaping the spaces, tried for loop on searchterm-it goes through each letter)

**Any ideas of how to get results from multiple words in searchterm?(e.g. 'driver 102' or 'R-22 red')**

```
     *xml doc:*

 <searchable_index>
   <Search>
     <title>driver</title>
     <keyword>101 101</keyword>
     <link>R-12</link>
     <color>white</color>
     <itemid>test</itemid>
   </Search>
   <Search>
    <title>driver</title>
    <keyword>102</keyword>
    <link>R-22</link>
    <color>red</color>
    <itemid>1test</itemid>
   </Search>
  </searchable_index>

    *Javascript:*

    function loadIndex() {

          if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
          xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
         xmlDoc.load("index9.xml");

          }

           else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
           xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
           xmlDoc.async = "false";
           xmlDoc.load("index9.xml");
           }
          } 



    function searchIndex() { 
        if (!xmlDoc) {
        loadIndex();
        }
        var searchterm = document.getElementById("searchme").value;
        searchtermconvert=searchterm.toString();
        var arrsearch=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Search");
        results = new Array;
                         if (searchtermconvert.length < 3) {
                        alert("Enter at least three characters");
                        } else {
                          for (var i=0;i<arrsearch.length;i++){
                                            var variable = arrsearch[i].textContent;
                                            var exp = new RegExp(searchtermconvert,"gi");
                                                    if ( variable.match(exp) != null) {                             
                                                    results.push(arrsearch[i]);
                                                    }   
                             }
                         showResults(results,searchtermconvert);
                         }
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

additional part that provided the search result of multiple search words:

```
                                            var exp = new RegExp(res[0],"i");
                                            var exp2 = new RegExp(res[1],"i");
                                            var exp3 = new RegExp(res[2],"i");
                                            var exp4 =new RegExp(res[3],"i");
                                            var exp5= new RegExp(res[4],"i");
```

then add extra conditions for the if statement

```
if ( variable.match(exp) != null && variable.match(exp2) != null && variable.match(exp3) != null && variable.match(exp4) != null && variable.match(exp5) != null)
```

and result is you can search with multiple search words.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
                              source code: 

        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
        <html> 
        <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="searchindex.js"></script>
        <style>
        body{
        width:1000px;
        margin:0px auto;
        position:relative;
        top:300px;
        }
        #dd{
        position:relative;
        background:red;
        border:4px solid yellow;

        }


        #dd1{
        text-align:center;

        }

        #searchProduct{
        text-align:center;
        position:relative;
        bottom:100px;
        font-size:24px;
        font-family:"Lucida Console";
        font-weight:bold;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>


        <div id="searchProduct">Search Product</div>
        <div id="dd1">
        <form id="dd" name="myForm" action="#">
        <input type="text" id="searchme" />
        <input type="submit" onclick="searchIndex(); return false; " /><!--return false;-->
        </form>
        </div>
        <div id="resultshere">
        </div>


        </body>
        </html>
```

/*----------------      Javascript --------------------*/

```
   window.onload = loadIndex;

   function loadIndex() { // load indexfile
   // most current browsers support document.implementation
   if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument) {
   xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("", "", null);
   xmlDoc.load("index9.xml");//showprices

   }
   // MSIE uses ActiveX
   else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
   xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
   xmlDoc.async = "false";
   xmlDoc.load("index9.xml");//showprices
   }
   }


   function clearBox()
   {
       document.getElementById("resultshere").innerHTML = "";
   }



   function searchIndex() { // search the index

        if (!xmlDoc) {//check whether xmlDoc is not a null
        loadIndex();
        }

        var searchterm = document.getElementById("searchme").value;
        searchtermconvert=searchterm.toString();
        var arrsearch=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Search");
        results = new Array;//declare new Array called results


            var res = searchtermconvert.split(' ');

        //  alert(res[0]);
        //  alert(res[1]);

                         if (res.length < 0) {// check if the seach term is not less than 3 characters
                        alert("Enter at least three characters");
                        } else {

                          for (var i=0;i<arrsearch.length;i++){

                                //if (x[i].textContent != null) {

                                            var variable = arrsearch[i].textContent;//starts from i+1 second

                                            var exp = new RegExp(res[0],"i");// declare a regular expression object which describes a pattern of characters
                                                var exp2 = new RegExp(res[1],"i");// declare a regular expression object which describes a pattern of characters
                                            var exp3 = new RegExp(res[2],"i");
                                            var exp4 =new RegExp(res[3],"i");
                                            var exp5= new RegExp(res[4],"i");


                                            //i-Perform case-insensitive matching    g-Perform a global match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match)  m-Perform multiline matching



                                                    if ( variable.match(exp) != null && variable.match(exp2) != null && variable.match(exp3) != null && variable.match(exp4) != null && variable.match(exp5) != null) {


                                                    results.push(arrsearch[i]);// and (if so) store it in an array


                                                    }   

                         }


                         showResults(results,res);

                         }

     }//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------end of searchIndex

   function showResults(results,res) {

                  if (results.length > 0) {

                 var resultshere = document.getElementById("resultshere"); // if there are any results, put them in a list inside the "resultshere" div
                 if (resultshere=>1){
                 clearBox();
                 }
                var header = document.createElement("h5");// just a markup for showing the results - heading
                var list = document.createElement("table");// just a markup for showing the results - unordered list

                var searchedfor = document.createTextNode("You've searched for " + res) ;
                resultshere.appendChild(header);// just a markup for showing the results - header
                header.appendChild(searchedfor);// just a markup for showing the results - "You've searched for "
                resultshere.appendChild(list);// just a markup for showing the results -  list = document.createElement("ul");

                                 for (var i=0;i<results.length;i++) { // go through results  Array from searchIndex()

                                //var x = ff;
                                var listitem = document.createElement("tr"); // create list item for var list = document.createElement("ul");
                                var list_td= document.createElement("td");
                                var item = document.createTextNode(results[i].textContent);
                                //var item2 = document.createTextNode(arrsearch[0].textContent);
                                //alert(arrsearch[0].textContent);
                                //alert(results[i].textContent);
                                //  list.appendChild(item2); 
                                list.appendChild(listitem);  // combine var list = document.createElement("ul"); with var listitem = document.createElement("li");
                                listitem.appendChild(item); // attach parameter item(var item = document.createTextNode(results[i].lastChild.nodeValue);) to the listitem(var item = document.createTextNode(results[i].lastChild.nodeValue);)


                                }//------------------------------------------------------------------end of for loop for (var i=0;i<results.length;i++)
                }
                else {
            // else tell the user no matches were found
                                                                                            var resultshere = document.getElementById("resultshere");// reach the element with "resultshere"
                                                                                            var para = document.createElement("p");// create and element(in this case a paragraph) for showing the "resultshere"
                                                                                            var notfound = document.createTextNode("Sorry, I couldn't find anything like "+res +"!");//create a text with a searchterm attachment
                                                                                            resultshere.appendChild(para);// append to resultshere a para variable which contains(var para = document.createElement("p"))
                                                                                            para.appendChild(notfound);// append to para variable which contains(var notfound = document.createTextNode("Sorry, I couldn't find anything like "+searchterm +"!");)

                }


      }
```

/*---------------------------XML----------------------*/

```
             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <searchable_index>
        <Search>
 <title>driver</title>
    <keyword>101 101</keyword>
    <link>R-12</link>
        <color>white</color>
    <itemid>test</itemid>
      </Search>
      <Search>
       <title>driver</title>
    <keyword>102</keyword>
    <link>R-22</link>
        <color>red</color>
 <itemid>1test</itemid>
      </Search>
    <Search>
     <title>driver</title>
    <keyword>101</keyword>
    <link>R-12 yellow</link>
        <color>yellow</color>
 <itemid>2_3_test</itemid>
      </Search>
      <Search>
       <title>hammer</title>
    <keyword>102</keyword>
    <link>R-22</link>
        <color>yellow</color>
 <itemid>3test</itemid>
      </Search>
    <Search>
     <title>saw</title>
    <keyword>101</keyword>
    <link>R-12</link>
        <color>black yellow</color>
 <itemid>001</itemid>
      </Search>
      <Search>
       <title>driver</title>
            <keyword>102 dewalt</keyword>
            <link>R-23</link>
           <color>redyellow</color>
    <itemid>100</itemid>
      </Search>
        <Search>
         <title>driver</title>
            <keyword>102</keyword>
            <link>R-23</link>
           <color>blackblack</color>
    <itemid>100</itemid>
      </Search>
          <Search>
         <title>driver</title>
            <keyword>101 101</keyword>
            <link>R-12</link>
        <color>white</color>
    <itemid>test</itemid>
      </Search>
      <Search>
       <title>driver</title>
            <keyword>102</keyword>
            <link>R-22</link>
        <color>red</color>
         <itemid>1test</itemid>
      </Search>
    <Search>
     <title>driver</title>
            <keyword>101</keyword>
            <link>R-12 yellow</link>
        <color>yellow</color>
         <itemid>2_3_test</itemid>
      </Search>
      <Search>
       <title>hammer</title>
            <keyword>102</keyword>
            <link>R-22</link>
        <color>yellow</color>
         <itemid>3test</itemid>
      </Search>
    <Search>
     <title>saw</title>
            <keyword>101</keyword>
            <link>R-12</link>
        <color>black yellow</color>
         <itemid>001</itemid>
      </Search>
      <Search>
       <title>driver</title>
            <keyword>102 dewalt</keyword>
            <link>R-23</link>
           <color>redyellow</color>
            <itemid>100</itemid>
      </Search>
        <Search>
         <title>driver</title>
            <keyword>102</keyword>
            <link>R-23</link>
           <color>blackblack</color>
    <itemid>100</itemid>
      </Search>
          <Search>
         <title>driver</title>
            <keyword>101 101</keyword>
            <link>R-12</link>
        <color>white</color>
    <itemid>test</itemid>
      </Search>
      <Search>
       <title>driver</title>
            <keyword>102</keyword>
            <link>R-22</link>
                <color>red</color>
         <itemid>1test</itemid>
      </Search>
    <Search>
     <title>driver</title>
            <keyword>101</keyword>
            <link>R-12 yellow</link>
        <color>yellow</color>
         <itemid>2_3_test</itemid>
      </Search>
      <Search>
       <title>hammer</title>
            <keyword>102</keyword>
            <link>R-22</link>
        <color>yellow</color>
         <itemid>3test</itemid>
      </Search>
    <Search>
     <title>saw</title>
            <keyword>101</keyword>
            <link>R-12</link>
        <color>black yellow</color>
         <itemid>001</itemid>
      </Search>
      <Search>
       <title>driver</title>
            <keyword>102 dewalt</keyword>
            <link>R-23</link>
           <color>redyellow</color>
    <itemid>100</itemid>
      </Search>
        <Search>
         <title>driver</title>
            <keyword>102</keyword>
            <link>R-23</link>
           <color>blackblack</color>
    <itemid>100</itemid>
      </Search>
    </searchable_index>
```