# Javascript search XML by Tag and get the sibling nodes

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am new to javascript and xml and am having an issue searching for a value in an xml file and displaying the related node values. I have notepad and IE 8 to work with and was trying to follow [search xml file for any occurrence in search string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850544/search-xml-file-for-any-occurrence-in-search-string). I was able to cobble together something that worked could not get the code given to work; but, it just brings back the tag I searched using getElementsByTagName.

I am working with an xml that is being generated by someone else and I have no control over the xml so for each, I do not even know what to call them, I want to call them a recordset, ?node family? it might not have all the fields.
Example: books-> title, author, year and price
while another one will be 
Example: books-> title, author, year
So I would like to search by title and bring back the related fields. Am looking to see if this is possible using the tools I have available, no jsquery, Ajax, XPath....
I checked w3 schools http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_element_firstchild.asp and it has I think what I need but can not get the search function(from the stack overflow link) to work.

Have tried to add the latest code I was working with; but, my brain is dead and cannot not seem to get it to display nicely.

XML = "test.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
  <dataroot>
  <XML_x0020_Export>
  <ID>142450</ID> 
  <LI>B</LI> 
  <FI>G</FI> 
  <Status>Available</Status> 
  <Status-Date>2014-11-14T00:00:00</Status-Date> 
  <Status-Loc>Web</Status-Loc> 
  </XML_x0020_Export>
  <XML_x0020_Export>
  <ID>144230</ID> 
  <LI>F</LI> 
  <FI>T</FI> 
  <Status>Available</Status> 
  <Status-Date>2014-11-14T00:00:00</Status-Date> 
  <Status-Loc>In House</Status-Loc> 
  </XML_x0020_Export>
  <XML_x0020_Export>
  <ID>144240</ID> 
  <LI>F</LI> 
  <FI>P</FI> 
  <Status>NA</Status> 
  </XML_x0020_Export>
  </dataroot>
```

HTML = "new_test.htm"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
  <title>Read XML in Microsoft Browsers</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var xmlDoc;
    function loadxml()
    {
      xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
      xmlDoc.async = false;
      xmlDoc.onreadystatechange = readXML;
      xmlDoc.load("test.xml");
    }
    function readXML()
    {
       if(xmlDoc.readyState == 4)
       {
    var foundElements = []; 
    arrayOfElements = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("XML_x0020_Export");
    for (i=0;i<arrayOfElements.length;i++)
        {
        if (arrayOfElements[i].ID == 144230) 
            {           
            foundElements.push(arrayOfElements[i]);
            document.write("<br>" + "Match Found: " + i);
            document.write("<br>");
            }
        for (i=0;i<arrayOfElements.length;i++)
            {
            document.write("<br>");
            document.write("Not Found: " + i + "|nodeName: " + " " + arrayOfElements[i].nodeName + "|nodeValue: " + arrayOfElements[i].nodeValue);
            document.write("<br>" + "Parent Node = " + arrayOfElements[1].parentNode.nodeName); 
            }
        }
    }
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="loadxml();">
 </body>
</html>
```

I am hoping to get something so I can write to the html:

1. ID = 144230; LI = F; FI = T; Status = Available; Status-Date =
   2014-11-14T00:00:00; Status-Loc = In House

but if I search by "144240" it would just write:

1. ID = 144240; LI = F; FI = P; Status = NA

But right now all I get is:

Not Found: 0|nodeName: XML_x0020_Export|nodeValue: null

Parent Node = dataroot

Not Found: 1|nodeName: XML_x0020_Export|nodeValue: null

Parent Node = dataroot

Not Found: 2|nodeName: XML_x0020_Export|nodeValue: null

Parent Node = dataroot

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have fixed several things in this.  First, you wouldn't ever really be trying to load an xml file locally...  You would get the xml file from a web service or something along those lines, and then you would operate on it.  This has been answered many times on stack overflow and I have removed it from the complexity of your situation.  So I have converted your xml file to a string, using new lines to concatenate it.

Second, I think I should just walk through the lines of code, explaining as we go.

```
var foundElements = []; 
arrayOfElements = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("XML_x0020_Export");
```

This did not change, we instantiate our array and load it with our xml elements.

```
for (i=0;i<arrayOfElements.length;i++)
```

This starts a loop.  We want to loop through the starting index of the array (0), go until we hit the length of the array, and increment our counter by 1 on every iteration.

```
var output = "";
```

This is us instantiating our output string for each element.

```
for (x=0; x<arrayOfElements[i].childNodes.length; x++) {
```

This starts a second loop within our loop.  We want to iterate over the XML Nodes in each xml element of our previous loop.  We use arrayOfElements[i].childNodes to return all child nodes (ID, Status, Etc). Then once again we want to start at the starting index of our our array (0), we want to go until we've reached the end of our child nodes.

```
if (arrayOfElements[i].childNodes[x].nodeType == 1) {
```

We only want to operate on nodes that have a nodeType of 1.  These are our attribute nodes, and contain the data we really care about.

```
output += arrayOfElements[i].childNodes[x].nodeName + ": " + arrayOfElements[i].childNodes[x].firstChild.nodeValue + "\n";
```

Then we concatenate our string with the child nodes name (title) and value (value).

```
document.write(output);
document.write("<br>");
```

Once we hit the last node in our element, we want to write to the html, and loop through to our next element.

This all works for me, and it should help give you an idea of how to navigate xml documents.  One thing that it seems you are not using is Javascript's built in debugging.  I am not certain how complex javascript programming would be possible without this, and it was crucial in my writing this response to you.

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

Final Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
  <title>Read XML in Microsoft Browsers</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var xmlDoc;
    function loadxml()
    {
      parser=new DOMParser();
      xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(  "<dataroot> \n" +
                                      "<XML_x0020_Export> \n" +
                                      "<ID>142450</ID>  \n" +
                                      "<LI>B</LI>  \n" +
                                      "<FI>G</FI>  \n" +
                                      "<Status>Available</Status>  \n" +
                                      "<Status-Date>2014-11-14T00:00:00</Status-Date>  \n" +
                                      "<Status-Loc>Web</Status-Loc>  \n" +
                                      "</XML_x0020_Export> \n" +
                                      "<XML_x0020_Export> \n" +
                                      "<ID>144230</ID>  \n" +
                                      "<LI>F</LI>  \n" +
                                      "<FI>T</FI>  \n" +
                                      "<Status>Available</Status>  \n" +
                                      "<Status-Date>2014-11-14T00:00:00</Status-Date>  \n" +
                                      "<Status-Loc>In House</Status-Loc>  \n" +
                                      "</XML_x0020_Export> \n" +
                                      "<XML_x0020_Export> \n" +
                                      "<ID>144240</ID>  \n" +
                                      "<LI>F</LI>  \n" +
                                      "<FI>P</FI>  \n" +
                                      "<Status>NA</Status>  \n" +
                                      "</XML_x0020_Export> \n" +
                                      "</dataroot>",
                                    "text/xml");
    }
    function readXML()
    {
        var foundElements = []; 
        arrayOfElements = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("XML_x0020_Export");
        for (i=0;i<arrayOfElements.length;i++)
            {
            var output = "";
            for (x=0; x<arrayOfElements[i].childNodes.length; x++) {
                if (arrayOfElements[i].childNodes[x].nodeType == 1) {    
                    output += arrayOfElements[i].childNodes[x].nodeName + ": " + arrayOfElements[i].childNodes[x].firstChild.nodeValue + "\n";
                }
            }
            document.write(output);
            document.write("<br>");
        }
    }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload="loadxml(); readXML()">
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for the response. I can not seem to get it to work. I have updated my question with the code I am currently working on and a portion of the xml along with what I want to do, hopefully this makes it a little clearer.

Comment: I have updated based on your updated question/code...  Please let me know if it works!